# jquery - custom bind events error in FF

Tags: jquery, bind, custom-event

Morning, I have an error appearing in firfox:

> TypeError: handlers.push is not a function
>       handlers.push( handleObj );

The error is caused from binding to a custom event

```
_submit.bind('watch.changed', function () {
    var $ob = $(this);
    if ($ob.attr('disabled') && $ob.attr('disabled') === 'disabled') {
        $tmp.attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('disabled');
    } else {
        $tmp.removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('disabled');
    }
});
```

Has anyone come accros this or know of a way around it?

regards

Comment: Interesting. What version of JQ? Can you reproduce in a Fiddle?

Comment: How to reproduce - on load? Should I click the link? No errors either way for me. Tested Chrome/Opera.

Comment: run in FireFox 14.0.1. The error will display in the dialog box. Only happens in FireFox

Comment: fixed this by changing watch.changed to watchChange. If someone can help me understand why that would be great

Comment: `watch.change` suggests an event named `watch` which is namespaced as `change`. `watchChange` suggests an event named `watchChange`, no namespacing. Perhaps jQ in FF doesn't like namespaced custom events.